# What are the differences between a physical node and a virtual one?

Tags: hadoop, nodes

Can someone explain what are the differences between a physical node and a virtual one and which one is potentially better . I've been looking for information but I haven't found anything.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "virtual node"? you mean a node process running on a single thread of a machine?

Comment: Yes. I am refering to that

Comment: Although this can get to an opinion-based semi-answer, I would like to say that in terms of "potentially better" it all depends on the data itself. You can't expect the same type of performance in a WordCount example and a classification algorythm in Hadoop. That's why you tend to test splitting the data to see what works best. For example if you have 3 quadcore machines in your cluster, test your application out by splitting the input data to 3 and then 3*4=12 pieces to see what is better (in terms of execution time, at least)

Comment: Where in the Hadoop documentation does it refer to anything as a virtual node? Sounds like you're asking about virtual cpu cores, which is unrelated to hadoop